# why uploading images to firebase storage from react native app on IOS device fails?

Tags: firebase, react-native, file-upload, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload images from my react native app to firebase storage. The images are uploaded successfully on Android devices and IOS simulators. However, they fail on IOS devices. I'm getting the following error:
NativeFirebaseError: [storage/unknown] An unknown error has occurred. (underlying reason 'Can not finalize upload.  Current size is 0.  Expected final size is 201112.')

**I used react-native-image-crop-picker 0.38.0**

```
 const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          cropping: true
        }).then((image) => {
            const imageUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.sourceURL : image.path
            console.log(imageUri)
        })
        .catch((e) =>{
            console.log(e)
        })
      }
```

## **Firebase implementations - **

**My podfile looks like this**

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static


target 'zaater' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  #Storage troubleshooting
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  # Flags change depending on the env values.xx
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'zaaterTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

**for my AppDelegate.mm file I added the following:**

```
#import <Firebase.h>

if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
```

*I added the GoogleService-info.plist file to the iOS directory (same level as podfile)
I also added it to XCODE.*

**My upload function Looks something like this: **

```
const uploadImage =  async (image) => {
        try {
            const uploadUri = image
            let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        
            // Add timestamp to File Name
            const extension = filename.split('.').pop();
            const name = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
            filename = name + Date.now() + '.' + extension

            //Store image
            const storageRef = storage().ref(`users/${idx}/${filename}`)
            const task = storageRef.putFile(uploadUri)
           
            //get image URL after being downloaded to firebase storage
            await task
            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
            return url
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            return null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo for uploading Image files to Firebase Storage Bucket.

Checkout on [Upload Image Tutorial](https://instamobile.io/mobile-development/react-native-firebase-storage/)

Comment: I actually came across this article however Im using react-native-image-crop-picker and I need to check again the string return again. It might be causing the problem. thanks for the response.

Comment: Okay check and update here! @KhaledAhmed

Comment: I actually solved the problem last night finally! I've never had a bug that bugged me for two weeks straight. I was using this piece of code:
const imageUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.sourceURL : image.path
and I did not need to do that. image.path works for both devices. It seems that the image picker package I was using took care of that internally! 
anyway, thank you very much buddy for the efforts.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is solved, I would suggest use console.log for easy debugging